# Pass value to lightning components from visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning

When the button is clicked `jumpCmp1()`, I need to pass the `phoneNumber` parameter to `component 1`

When the button is clicked `jumpCmp2()`, I need to pass the `phoneNumber` parameter to `component 2`

I tried to use `Event` to solve my problem, but it didn't work

The referenced `component` is [Lightning Open CTI](https://developer.salesforce.com/wiki/lightning_open_cti) , So I cannot use LWC.

---

VF Page

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeLightning />
    
    <script src="/support/api/52.0/interaction.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/support/api/52.0/lightning/opencti.js"></script>
    <div id="lightning"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function jumpCmp1() {
            var phoneNumber = '456';
            // fireEvent();
            document.getElementById('container1').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('container2').style.display = 'none';
        }
        function jumpCmp2() {
            var phoneNumber = '123';
            // fireEvent();
            document.getElementById('container1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('container2').style.display = 'block';
        }
        
        Object.entries({
            container1:'c:Test1Cmp',
            container2: 'c:Test2Cmp'
        }).forEach(
            function([containerName, componentName]) {
                $Lightning.use("c:TestApp", function() {
                    $Lightning.createComponent(componentName, {"xyz" : "parameters"}, containerName, function() {
                        console.log(`Loaded component ${containerName}`);
                    });
                });
            }
        )

        function fireEvent() {           
            var myEvent = $A.get("e.c:testEvent");
            console.log('myEvent:'+myEvent);
            myEvent.fire();
        }

    </script>
    <div id="container1" style="display: none"></div>
    <div id="container2" style="display: none"></div>
    <div name = 'test' style="margin-top: 15px;">
        <button onclick="jumpCmp2();">Go to page 2</button>
        <button onclick="jumpCmp1();">Go to page 1</button>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;">
        <input type="hide" id="phoneHide"/>
        <input type="hide" id="callIdHide"/>
        <input type="hide" id="callTypeHide"/>
    </div>
    
</apex:page>
```

---

APP

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" description="The Lightning Out app which hosts the demo adapter."> 
    <aura:dependency resource="c:Test1Cmp"/>
    <aura:dependency resource="c:Test2Cmp"/>
</aura:application>
```

---

EVENT

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION">
    <aura:attribute name="parentName" type="String"/>
</aura:event>
```

---

Test1Cmp.cmp

```
<aura:component description="The container component that houses the UI of the adapter.">
    <aura:handler action="{!c.init}" name="init" value="{!this}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="phoneNumber" type="String" access="public" />
    <div class="slds-box">
        <center>
            <div> --- Component 1 ---</div>
        </center>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

---

Test1Cmp.js

```
({
    init : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('component 1 ');
        var phoneNumber = component.get("v.phoneNumber");
        console.log('component 1111 = ' + phoneNumber);
    }
})
```

---

Test2Cmp.cmp

```
<aura:component description="The container component that houses the UI of the adapter.">
    <aura:handler action="{!c.init}" name="init" value="{!this}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="phoneNumber" type="String" access="public" />
    <div class="slds-box">
        <center>
            <div> --- Component 2 ---</div>
        </center>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

---

Test2Cmp.js

```
({
    init : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('component 2 ');
        var phoneNumber = component.get("v.phoneNumber");
        console.log('component 2222 = ' + phoneNumber);
    }
})
```

Comment: I searched for a long time and couldn't find the relevant information.